# Add combobox parameter to iReport's report

Tags: parameters, jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

In *iReport 4.8.0*, I want to enable the user to choose a parameter value from a Combobox / list / Dropdown / collection (whatever you choose) and the value that he chooses will be inserted into the query.

I already created a string parameter that prompts when I preview the report and the string is inserted into the query. It works great, but now I need to define a combobox.

I need to provide names of cities so my query is:

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(leads.`status`) AS Number_Of_Status,
  leads.`status` AS leads_status,
  leads.`primary_address_city` AS leads_primary_address_city,
  leads.id AS lead_id
FROM
      `leads` leads
 WHERE
      leads.`primary_address_city` = $P{city_combobox}
 GROUP BY
      leads.`status`
```

I tried to make the `city_combobox` parameter a `java.util.List` but I get `Parameter type not supported` error and I also don't know where to load the strings into it.

I don't know anything about *JasperReports Server*, I didn't install it, only *iReport* is installed and up to know i did everything with it.

So I'm looking for a way to do that in *iReport* only, without an input control of *JR Server*. It will be enough for me to just provide the report with a manually inserted values into the combobox, it doesn't have to even be a query. For example, insert "NY","Miami", "Washington" into a list parameter, but how and where do I do that?

Comment: This is not a function that can be built into JasperReports/iReport. If you are deploying the report through JasperReports Server it is done there. If you are deploying it through your own application, you have to do it yourself in the app. I do not use JasperReports Server, so I unfortunately can not give you any directions on adding the input control there.

Comment: @Rodniko The *iReport* is just a GUI designer for creating report's templates. It is not an application for an end-user for running report and getting the result in some supported formats. You can use *JR Server* for deploying and running reports (get in some format) or you can create your own application, for example on Java for building reports (with setting report's parameters)

Comment: Thank you , i guess i'll have to install Jasperreport server and learn it... i wanted to save myself from doing that because the documentation is so poor... but thank you for clearing that out. the other reports i made in the Ireport , including reports with string parameters , works great on zuckerreport. all i need now is a report with drop down...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem. it turns out zuckerreport is based on jasperreport server and therefore can add input controls too.

The solution is to create the "city_combobox" parameter as a string parameter and leave the query as is , like the above example i gave. thats it for the IReport.

in zuckerreport, add a parameter that its "Default Parameter Name" named city_combobox.

for a dropdown parameter choose a parameter of type of "user-defined Query" and fill the “Parameter Settings” and “User-Defined Query” fields with a query that will fill the dropdown with a list of values, for example:

SELECT DISTINCT
leads.primary_address_city AS leads_primary_address_city
FROM
leads leads

if you can't see the  “Parameter Settings” and “User-Defined Query” fields (in the new version of zuckerreport they are hidden), then

This code is needed to be added manually in the editview code of zuckerreport.
Add this code in modules/zr2_ReportParameter/metadata/editviewdefs.php :

5 =>
        array (
            0 => 'range_options',
  ),

now rebuild and then you'll see the hidden fields.

Create a new template using “jasperReports Template” on the menu, the template is actually the report:

a. Choose a name for the template and choose the jrxml file of the report .
b. Choose PDF , Excel and HTML.
c. Save

Create a new Parameter binding between the report and the parameter:
a. Push “Create”
b. The parameter name has to be the exact parameter name in the IReport.
c. Choose the report and the parameter and no need to choose “Bind to module”

Copy the .jasper file of the report into custom/zuckerreports2/resources in SugarCRM.
Go to “On demand reporting”, choose the report and the parameter is supposed to show.

There you go! :)