# Loading values in ireport parameters box

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

In ireport when clicking on preview, and you have parameters, you'll get a parameter box where you put a certain value to get specific record(s).Now i am trying to put specific values in the parameter box, so that the user would choose between it.
[image]

The same goal as in this so question : [Loading promt box with parameters in iReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239843/loading-promt-box-with-parameters-in-ireport)

However i want to do it without using Jasper Server. Is it possible to achieve this only from  within IReport Designer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,right click on the input control and select to add the local input control and provide id and name for the input control
Under the input control details select single select list of values if you have the list of values with you or if you want to add the data of a column as drill down select single select select query and extract that field.

This will help you to drill down the data.

Thanks and Regards
Megha

Comment: Which input control?, in  iReport?.. are you really sure?, I think you are speaking about the jasper server interfaces...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can **not** do this in iReport preview. Have no clue what @Megha is refereeing to....

You can provide default value for your parameter through the `<defaultValueExpression>` tag and decide if you wan't it to prompt or not to prompt with the `isForPrompting` attribute.

Why can't we have select list, well I guess iReport is a **tool for developers**, so the preview is only to test the report. For customers jasper soft have developed the jasper report server.

And remember you can always develop your own interface (in swing or on the web)